# Posizione dell'aggettivo: nuova auto - auto nuova

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-order

Questi due esempi sono compatibili o uno dei due non è corretto?

> Ci sono poi alcuni aggettivi che, quando vengono posizionati prima del
> nome, assumono un significato diverso, figurato. [...]
>
> "Maria ha comprato un'auto nuova" = nuova, non usata
> "Maria ha comprato una nuova auto" = un'altra auto (fig)

---

> Talvolta la diversa posizione serve ad indicare la diversa funzione
> dell'aggettivo: descrittiva (prima del nome) o restrittiva (dopo il
> nome). [...]
>
> "Marta guida la sua nuova auto"
> "Marta guida la sua auto nuova" = non quella vecchia

Fonte: [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/xbcLNKkihSs)

Comment: Generalmente l'aggettivo messo prima, qualifica; messo dopo, distingue. Ci sono poi casi particolari come "auto nuova" e "nuova auto", ma sono speciali. Quindi la risposta per me è sì, entrambe le affermazioni sono vere e compatibili fra loro.

Comment: Precisazione riguardo alla seconda affermazione: io non direi "talvolta" ma direi "solitamente".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effetti, il significato di "nuova auto" e "auto nuova" è diverso. Spesso, quando l'aggettivo precede il nome ha una funzione descrittiva; invece, quando lo precede, ha una funzione distintiva.

Puoi vederlo, per esempio, nel libro *Grammatica. Competenze di base*, volume 1 di  Marialuisa Pioretti, edito da La Spiga Edizioni:

> L'aggettivo può precedere il nome (**valore descrittivo**): *Mio cugino vive in un grande
> appartamento*; o può seguirlo (**valore distintivo**): *Lo zio vuole acquistare un appartamento grande*. Nel secondo caso l'aggettivo ha un'importanza maggiore e una diversa sfumatura di significato. A volte il significato cambia: *Ho comprato una nuova auto* (ne ho comprata un'altra). *Ho comprato un'auto nuova* (non usata).

La questione della diversa funzione degli aggettivi qualificativi a seconda della loro posizione è anche spiegata nel'*Italiano* di Serianni, nella sezione V.32:

> A seconda che precedano o seguano il
> nome, molti aggettivi qualificativi possono assumere una funzione *descrittiva* o
> una funzione *restrittiva*.

In questo libro puoi trovare alcuni esempi e una spiegazione più dettagliata di questo argomento.

Per quanto riguarda i diversi significati di "nuovo", questi si possono trovare nel [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nuovo). In particolare, si può leggere quanto segue, in cui si fa esplicitamente menzione alla differenza di significato tra "auto nuova" e "nuova auto":

> **1.** In genere, di cosa fatta o avvenuta o manifestatasi da poco, spesso in contrapp. diretta a vecchio, antico, e quindi con sign. prossimo a recente, attuale, moderno, ma con notevole varietà di accezioni; [...] **a.** Con riferimento a cose materiali, prodotto, fabbricato o costruito da poco: *l’inaugurazione del n. ponte*; *le n. costruzioni in periferia* (e *case di n. costruzione*); *i quartieri n. della città* (e, con lo stesso senso, *la città n.*); *un’automobile n.*; *un televisore nuovo*. In molti casi si contrappone direttamente a usato (per cui la produzione o fabbricazione può anche non essere recente) [...] In queste accezioni, se adoperato come attributo, segue di solito il sost.: *una cravatta n.*, acquistata da poco, non usata (*una n. cravatta*, invece, di nuovo modello o disegno, oppure, spec. in usi region., un’altra, che si aggiunge a quelle già possedute; e così, *un’auto n.*, rispetto a *una n. auto*, ecc.).

E, più avanti, anche:

> **2.** Con sign. simile a altro (rispetto al passato, al precedente, o alla consuetudine, alla tradizione), in varie accezioni: [...]
> **b.** Che si aggiunge a ciò che già c’era o che si aveva prima (con questo sign., si colloca sempre prima del nome): *aprire n. sbocchi al commercio*; *la fabbrica ha bisogno di n. operai*; *non fa che comprare n. quadri*, *n. tappeti*; *ci saranno n. nomine*; *mi giungono sempre n. lagnanze*; *il malato ha avuto una n. crisi*.

Comment: Dissento, almeno nel caso dell'auto nuova. Nel parlato pochi direbbero “Maria ha comprato una nuova auto”, ma più probabilmente “Maria si è comprata la macchina nuova” per dire che ha cambiato automobile e “Maria si è comprata la macchina, nuova” (con piccola pausa) per sottolineare che non è usata.

Comment: Non so, @egreg: può darsi che nel parlato si usi dire in questo modo, ma quello che ho trovato nel Treccani sembra essere in accordo con la spiegazione di Pioretti.

Comment: Non ho detto che quella grammatica è “sbagliata”, anche se un po' troppo *tranchant*.

Comment: Aggiungerei che l'aggettivo "nuovo" è speciale, come speciali sono "bello" e "buono", per esempio. Nell'italiano comune è più frequente posporre l'aggettivo che metterlo prima: chi direbbe "Ho mangiato una rossa mela"? Però sarebbe comune dire "Ho mangiato una buona mela"; non è idiomatico "ho una robusta auto", ma lo è "ho un gran mal di testa". Da questo punto di vista, "comprare una nuova auto" suona normalissimo.

Answer (score 1):

Da madrelingua, direi che sono compatibili ed è l'uso a essere contraddittorio.

Comment: Quale delle due coppie di esempi (auto nuova, nuova auto) ti sembra più giusta?

Comment: @Charo ha spiegato molto bene, dipende dal contesto :)